# Creating a HTML block with childs an classes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, firebase

In my Firebase database(basically a javascript object) there is an array of Objects each object needs to be inserted into my HTML.

Each Object has 3 properties: dbIsNewExercise, dbExerciseName and dbExerciseTime. If the dbIsNewExercise property is set I want to insert some extra elements.

The HTML I try to create looks like this:

```
<section class="card oefening">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="oefening-icon"></div>
    <!-- The div.oefening-icon-nieuw only if the dbIsNewExercise property is set to true -->
    <div class="oefening-icon-nieuw"></div>
    <div class="oefening-info">
      <!-- H3 element only if the dbIsNewExercise property is set to true -->
      <h3>Nieuw</h3>
      <h4>- 15 min</h4>
    </div>
    <h2>Ritmisch ademen</h2>
    <div class="open-card-icon"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

There is also a parent element with an id of "oefeningen", so i can insert each HTML block as an child of #oefeningen.

But when i try to use the following JavaScript code I get an ReferenceError stating that "classList is not defined".

```
    // Method to get the last object in a array
    if (!Array.prototype.last){
        Array.prototype.last = function(){
            return this[this.length - 1];
        };
    };

    // The parent element
    var exercises = document.getElementById("oefeningen"),

    // The Object returned by the database it's tested and returns the correct object.
        changedData = snapshot.val(), 

        newSection = document.createElement("section"),
        newAncor = document.createElement("a"),
        newDiv = document.createElement("div"),
        newH2 = document.createElement("h2"),
        newH3 = document.createElement("h3"),
        newH4 = document.createElement("h4");

    var newCard = classList.add("card", "oefening"),
        newCardContainer = classList.add("card-container"),
        newOefeningIcon = classList.add("oefening-icon"),
        newOefeningIconNieuw = classList.add("oefening-icon-nieuw"),
        newOefeningInfoHolder = classList.add("oefening-info"),
        openCardIcon = classList.add("open-card-icon");

    exercises.appendChild(newSection.newCard);
    var card = document.getElementsByClassName('card').last();

    card.appendChild(newDiv.newCardContainer);
    var cardContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('card-container').last();

    cardContainer.appendChild(newDiv.newOefeningIcon);
    if (changedData.dbIsNewExercise == true) {
        cardContainer.appendChild(newDiv.newOefeningIconNieuw);
    }

    cardContainer.appendChild(newDiv.newOefeningInfoHolder);
    var oefeningInfoHolder = document.getElementsByClassName('oefening-info').last();

    if (changedData.dbIsNewExercise == true) {
        oefeningInfoHolder.appendChild(newH3);
        oefeningInfoHolder.appendChild(newH4);
    } else {
        oefeningInfoHolder.appendChild(newH4);
    }
    cardContainer.appendChild(newH2);
    cardContainer.appendChild(openCardIcon);

    newH2.innerHTML = changedData.dbExerciseName;

    if (changedData.dbIsNewExercise == true) {
        newH3.innerHTML = "Nieuw";
        newH4.innerHTML = " - " + changedData.dbExerciseTime + "min";
    } else {
        newH4.innerHTML = changedData.dbExerciseTime + "min";
    }
```

### The solution

For anyone who stumbles on this topic, the solution was given by @viveksinghggits in the comments. First create the elements, add the class lists to them, and then append them to a parent.

```
    var oefeningen = document.getElementById("oefeningen"),
        changedData = snapshot.val(),

        newCard = document.createElement("section"),
        newAncor = document.createElement("a"),
        newCardContainer = document.createElement("div"),
        newOefeningIcon = document.createElement("div"),
        newOefeningIconNieuw = document.createElement("div"),
        newOefeningInfo = document.createElement("div"),
        openCardIcon = document.createElement("div"),
        newH2 = document.createElement("h2"),
        newH3 = document.createElement("h3"),
        newH4 = document.createElement("h4");

    newCard.classList.add("card", "oefening");
    newCardContainer.classList.add("card-container");
    newOefeningIcon.classList.add("oefening-icon");
    newOefeningIconNieuw.classList.add("oefening-icon-nieuw");
    newOefeningInfo.classList.add("oefening-info");
    openCardIcon.classList.add("open-card-icon");

    newCard.appendChild(newAncor);
    newAncor.appendChild(newCardContainer);
    newCardContainer.appendChild(newOefeningIcon);
    if (changedData.dbIsNewExercise == true) {
        newCardContainer.appendChild(newOefeningIconNieuw);
    }

    newCardContainer.appendChild(newOefeningInfo);
    if (changedData.dbIsNewExercise == true) {
        newOefeningInfo.appendChild(newH3);
        newOefeningInfo.appendChild(newH4);
    } else {
        newOefeningInfo.appendChild(newH4);
    }
    newCardContainer.appendChild(newH2);
    newCardContainer.appendChild(openCardIcon);

    newH2.innerHTML = changedData.dbExerciseName;

    if (changedData.dbIsNewExercise == true) {
        newH3.innerHTML = "Nieuw";
        newH4.innerHTML = " - " + changedData.dbExerciseTime + "min";
    } else {
        newH4.innerHTML = changedData.dbExerciseTime + "min";
    }

    oefeningen.appendChild(newCard);
```

Comment: no jquery used? this can be done with better ease using Jquery

Comment: It looks like you're using `classList` incorrectly. It's an element property: `element.classList.add('hidden')`...

Comment: Because `classList` variable is not defined. classList needs to be used with HTMLElement.
Like newSection.classList.add(...)

Comment: @Andy @Vivek `newSection.newCard` would become: `document.createElement("section").classList.add("card", "oefening")` and there fore be assigned to a new element. Or do i have to use classList on an existing element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

classList is an object that should be called on an HTML element to add a class to it.
lets say I have a div element

```
<div id="newDiv" style="padding:10px; border:1px solid black;">
</div>
```

and i want to add a class "myClass" when the page has done loading, I would write

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
  var _divEle = document.getElementById("newDiv");
  _divEle.classList.add("myClass");//_divEle is an element whose ID is newDiv
});
```

when you open it in browser that div will  have the class "myClass".

Comment: I kinde get that, but i want to loop the Javascript for every object in the the array so there wouldn't be any HTML yet, except the parent `<div id="oefeningen"></div>`

Comment: You are creating a section element
`newSection = document.createElement("section")`
, if all you want to do is adding a class to it and appending it to the div with id oefeningen. You can do this
`newSection.classList.add(classesYouwanttoAdd);
exercises.appendChild(newSection);`